# Windows 8.1 Windows Deployment Service 2012 R2 drivers not installing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, drivers, wds, windows-8.1

I can't get the drivers to install for one of my Windows 8.1 images. There aren't any errors in the event log or any errors showing up during the installation it just doesn't install them. I have the driver path in my answer file for the WinPE, OfflineServicing, and AuditSystem passes and it looks something like this:

```
processorArchitecture="amd64" name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpCustomizationsWinPE">


-<DriverPaths>


-<PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="e3d3e806">

<Path>C:\RemoteInstall\Images\P7510\Out-of-Box Drivers</Path>


-<Credentials>

<Domain>XXX</Domain>

<Password>XXXXXXXXXX</Password>

<Username>XXXXXXXXX</Username>

</Credentials>

</PathAndCredentials>

</DriverPaths>
```

and I have made a driver group for the installation and imported all the necessary drivers into it just like i do for all my other images but this one just wont work and I'd like to figure out why

**UPDATE**
I just tried to image another laptop (different image and drivers) and now that image doesn't work aswell, we haven't changed anything with our server so i don't know whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, our network admin changed the DHCP settings without telling me and I needed to run few commands on WDS:

```
WDSUTIL /Set-Server /UseDHCPPorts:No /DHCPOption60:Yes
```

Which sets "Do not listen on port 67" and Configures DHCP "Option 60 to PXEClient"